# Unaccepted answers lead to mismatches in the daily reputation displays

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, unaccepted-answer

When one of my answers is unaccepted, the box showing the daily/weekly/monthly reputation change gets out of sync with the reputation page. In the picture below, note the daily reputation in the box at the top of the screen incorrectly displays 290, while the reputation tab correctly displays 275. I noticed that this happens only on the days when one of my answers is unaccepted.

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reputation history will always show you the **net effect** of all the events that occurred for that day. However, your unaccept didn't actually "lose you 15 reputation" today, but *reversed* the 15 reputation gain for whatever day the original accept occurred. So both values are correct. Your reputation changed 275 in the positive direction for the day, but you actually earned 290 for the day.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation. Would you agree that it is misleading to see these two numbers next to each other, under the same label? Should the label on the page say something like `today (cumulative)`, rather than simply `today`? The problem I see is that the two different numbers are labeled identically.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: [I do.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146682)