# How exactly do vote reversals interact with reputation calculation with respect to the daily rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-badges

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325661/526695) to [If I hit the daily rep cap and then get downvoted, does it still count towards badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70158/526695) details (emphasis mine):

> the script that awards the badge doesn't even look at
>   downvotes, [...] It only adds up the total
>   reputation you gained [..] to see if that amount is >= 200. It's even possible for a day to
>   count if you received a series of downvotes early on but still
>   accumulated 200 reputation after that and never even hit the
>   reputation cap. As long as you earned 200 that day.

How does that interact with the reversal from a Voting-correction?

This happened to me on [rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/). The [help centre on rpg.se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) states:

> Such votes will generally be invalidated as part of an automated
>   process that runs every day

It seems like this is different from the negative reputation that, technically, has no bearing on badge process. Invalidation seems to imply that the event, and thus it counting in regards to reputation gain is reversed.

So, how exactly do vote reversals interact with reputation calculation with respect to the daily reputation cap?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unaccepted answers lead to mismatches in the daily reputation displays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146675/282094) and   https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341395/282094 - In short: the reversal **counts for the day that is reversed**, not the *day* ***on*** *which* it is reversed. Every badge awarded is retained regardless, unless a Developer goes in and manually removes it - which would only be in rare cases, such as fraud.

Comment: @Rob I do not know. Invalidation seems to be different from unaccepting, as in, from my understanding of what I have cited, it reverses that you have earned the reputation instead of merely reversing the amount of awarded reputation.

Comment: @Rob ah, that makes sense.

Comment: If you are satisfied that either of those suggestions, or any other duplicates you find, answer your question you can close your own question as a duplicate; you can also leave it for other users to decide/vote on.

Comment: @Rob while there may be more nuance in here than in that question, I think it sufficiently answers mine, thanks.